# How to force "where" precedence when expanding views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say that I define:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateString] [VARCHAR](max)
)
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1](DateString) VALUES ('2014-10-20'),('BadDate');
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test1]
AS
    SELECT 
        Id,
        CONVERT(DATE,DateString) ConvertedDate
    FROM dbo.Test1
    WHERE isdate(DateString)=1
GO
```

The following query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_Test1]
```

The following query throws "**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string**".

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_Test1] WHERE ConvertedDate='2014-10-20'
```

Obviously this happens because the condition `ConvertedDate='2014-10-20'` gets executed before `isdate(DateString)=1`.

How would you go about fixing vw_Test1 so that it always works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way for these type of situations is using **CASE** statement, I think your view 
with should work.

```
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test1]
    AS
        SELECT 
            Id,
            case ISDATE(DateString) when 1 then CONVERT(DATE,DateString) else 0 --oranything
            end ConvertedDate
        FROM dbo.Test1
        WHERE isdate(DateString)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the version of SQL Server that you are using.  SQL Server 2012+ has `try_convert()`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test1] as
    SELECT Id, TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DateString) as ConvertedDate
    FROM dbo.Test1
    WHERE isdate(DateString) = 1;
```

This will return `NULL` if the conversion fails, rather than an error.

In general, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of components of a `select`.  The only exception is the `case` statement -- and this is a partial exception.  In any case, using a `case` also solves the problem:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test1] as
    SELECT Id,
           (CASE WHEN isdate(DateString) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE, DateString) END) as ConvertedDate
    FROM dbo.Test1
    WHERE isdate(DateString) = 1;
```

The lack of `ELSE` clause forces a `NULL` if the conversion does not take place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 or later try:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8570f/2)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateString] [VARCHAR](max)
);
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_Test1]
AS
    SELECT 
        Id,
        TRY_CONVERT(DATE,DateString) ConvertedDate
    FROM dbo.Test1
    WHERE isdate(DateString)=1;

GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1](DateString) VALUES ('2014-10-20'),('BadDate');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_Test1] WHERE ConvertedDate='2014-10-20'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8570f/2/0)**:

```
| ID | CONVERTEDDATE |
|----|---------------|
|  1 |    2014-10-20 |
```